# xpath expression to select an item whose ENTIRE text contents contains a specific string

Tags: xpath, concatenation

Can i have an xpath expression to select an item whose ENTIRE text contents (including its descendants') contains a specific string?

My xml is like this:

```
<item>
    <sentence>Good morning. Today is fine.</sentence>
    <entry>
        <keywords>
            <keyword>fooA</keyword>
            <keyword>fooB</keyword>
        </keywords>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <keywords>
            <keyword>fooC</keyword>
            <keyword>fooD</keyword>
        </keywords>
    </entry>
</item>
<item>
    <sentence>It's raining, we'd better get a raincoat.</sentence>
    <entry>
        <keywords>
            <keyword>barA</keyword>
            <keyword>barB</keyword>
        </keywords>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <keywords>
            <keyword>barC</keyword>
            <keyword>barD</keyword>
        </keywords>
    </entry>
</item>
```

What I want to get is. If I look up any word or words in:

```
"Good morning. Today is fine. fooA fooB fooC fooD"
```

like "morning", "fooC", or "fine fooB", I will get the first item.
and if I look up any word or words in:

```
"It's raining, we'd better get a raincoat.. barA barB barC barD"
```

like "raining", "better", "better barD", "get barB barA", i get the second item.

I'm trying to use contain() and concat(), but seemed I couldn't concatenate within the xpath expression all descendants in different levels.

```
contains(concat(sentence/text(),entry/keywords/keyword/text()),"barC")
```

not working. concat() only turns the first text node to string.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine

```
//item[contains(string(), 'barC')]
```

Demo here - http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/da560511673f56c89386aecfc15a4a63

If you only want to use specific child nodes, try this

```
//item[(sentence|entry)[contains(string(), 'barC')]]
```

Demo - http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8236042dbcceea163665b015aa4da180

Comment: Hi @Phil! Thanks! this works! and may I ask, if <item> has other children like <date> <time>, but I don't want these to be searched, but only in <sentence> and <entry>, can you please give a way for that? Thanks!

Comment: holy my!!  it works like charm! i worked on this for weeks and finally only came with a complex workaround. Thanks so much!!!